# onClickListener in ViewHolder only getting called sometimes

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I've got a RecyclerView with an Adapter and a ViewHolder in it.

```
   public class MainListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView nameLabel;

    public MainListViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);

        nameLabel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nameLabel);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        context = v.getContext();
    }



    public void bindEvent(Event e){
        nameLabel.setText(e.getName().toUpperCase());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.v(TAG, "ViewHolder onClick triggered");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, EventViewPagerActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The onClick however is only getting called sometimes, i can't find a specific pattern when it is executed.

EDIT:

Added this now to my Root of the ListItem.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

and

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in each child item.

this doens't help unfortunately.

Comment: one of the child view of `v` must be holding focus.

Comment: i want the whole listitem to be clickable thought.

Comment: Yeah but, one of the item child must be holding focus. Try adding`focusableInTouchMode="false"` in each child item.

Comment: edited first post, tried adding `focusableInTouchMode="false"` in each child item aswell

Answer (score 0):

Some child view in your ViewHolder is focusable, try adding this to the root item in your ViewHolder layout xml

```
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```